# Implementation of nested pairs

Tags: python, data-structures, nested

I'm doing Advent of Code and until this point I had no problem to solve issues on my own until day 18 which got me. I want to solve it on my own but I feel like I can't even start however the task itself is not difficult. It's kinda long to elaborate but the point is the following:

I have to implement nested pairs, so every item of a pair can be an another pair and so on, for example:

`[[[[[9,8],1],2],3],4]`

`[[3,[2,[1,[7,3]]]],[6,[5,[4,[3,2]]]]]`

I have to do different operations on these pairs, such as deleting pairs on a very deep level and use its values at higher level. I know Python handles tuples really great but I have yet to find a solution for recursive (?) traversal, deletion and "saving" values from the "deep". It's not a wise solution to delete items during iterating. Shall I use a different approach or some custom data structure for a task like this? I don't need an exact solution just some generic guidance.

Comment: Python tuples are non-mutable. So you can write a function that takes a tuple, and returns a different tuple, but you can't write a function that takes a tuple, and modifies that tuple in-place. Python lists, by contrast, are mutable. So you can modify a list or one of its sublists in-place. But as you noted, you have to be careful in that case, not to iterate and delete on the same list at the same time. Although if each list has only 2 elements, that shouldn't be too much of an issue.

Comment: `"I have to implement nested pairs"`...it might be worth stepping back and asking if this true. A better way to model this might be a tree. One of the things you'll notice in a tree representation is that if you do certain kinds of traversals the pairs you need to "explode" will appear in order. That might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read problem 18 from advent of code, but here is an example answer to your question with a list version and a tuple version.

Imagine I have nested pairs, and I want to write a function that delete all the deepest pairs and replaced them with a single number being the sum of the two numbers in the pair. For example:

```
input                            -> output
(1, 2)                           -> 3
((1, 2), 3)                      -> (3, 3)
(((1,2), (3,4)), ((5,6), (7,8))) -> ((3, 7), (11, 15))
((((((1, 2), 3), 4), 5), 6), 7)  -> (((((3, 3), 4), 5), 6), 7)
```

Here is a version with immutable tuples, that returns a new tuple:

```py
def updated(p):
    result, _ = updated_helper(p)
    return result

def updated_helper(p):
    if isinstance(p, tuple) and len(p) == 2:
        a, b = p
        new_a, a_is_number = updated_helper(a)
        new_b, b_is_number = updated_helper(b)
        if a_is_number and b_is_number:
            return a+b, False
        else:
            return (new_a, new_b), False
    else:
        return p, True
```

Here is a version with mutable lists, that returns nothing useful but mutates the list:

```py
def update(p):
    if isinstance(p, list) and len(p) == 2:
        a, b = p
        a_is_number = update(a)
        b_is_number = update(b)
        if isinstance(a, list) and len(a) == 1:
            p[0] = a[0]
        if isinstance(b, list) and len(b) == 1:
            p[1] = b[0]
        if a_is_number and b_is_number:
            p[:] = [a+b]
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Note how I used a substantive, `updated`, and a verb, `update`, to highlight the different logic between these two similar functions. Function `update` performs an action (modifying a list), whereas `updated(p)` doesn't perform any action, but *is* the updated pair.

Testing:

```py
print( updated( (((1,2), (3,4)), ((5,6), (7,8))) ) )
# ((3, 7), (11, 15))

l = [[[1,2], [3,4]], [[5,6], [7,8]]]
update(l)
print(l)
# [[3, 7], [11, 15]]
```